# Get HTML for particular id from dynamically rendered templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a ajax call which replaces the certain section in my page with the jquery template on its success.

```
   $.ajax({
            url: '${url}',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {

                $('#someId').replaceWith($('#myTemplate').tmpl({info: data}));
            },
        });
```

Now i am trying to get html content only for small section from this template as

```
var innerInfo= $("#exampleId").html();
```

but getting undefined in innerInfo. Also, below code gives me alert as 0.

```
alert($("#exampleId").length)
```

Can anyone please help me out on this,what exactly is happening here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At which point in your code are you attempting to interact with `#exampleId`?

Comment: Can you show your HTML after the replace has occurred? It may be a side-effect of the templating, but just guessing without seeing the HTML. A JsFiddle would be useful.

Comment: Make sure selectors are valid, and make sure you do this when the document is ready.

Comment: @Rory:Trying to interact on a button click,where i am trying to get the html for this id for some further modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
var innerInfo= $("#exampleId").html();
```

with

```
var innerInfo1 = '';

setTimeout(function () { innerInfo1= $("#exampleId1").html(); }, 0);
```

and see if it helps....

Comment: It did work,can this be done if i have 2 different id's and want to do same procedure for both.i tried but it didn't work.

Comment: post a new question  i would suggest